# ggplot2: ordering factor levels appears to have no effect on figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I apologize for the semmingly simple nature of this query, but I have been beating my head on why this does not work.

So, here is a simple reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
dm <- diamonds
ggplot(dm, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + geom_violin()
```

and I get the following plot (as I should):

[image]

But I want the violins in the figure to be of the form

```
> "Ideal"     "Fair"      "Very Good" "Premium"   "Good"
```

so I reorder the factor levels:

```
levels(dm$cut) <- levels(dm$cut)[c(5, 1, 3, 4, 2)]
levels(dm$cut)
[1] "Ideal"     "Fair"      "Very Good" "Premium"   "Good"
```

However, when I try the following:

```
ggplot(dm, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + geom_violin()
```

I get the violins in the same order as before, but the labels in the order as I want them. How do I fix this problem? TIA for any help and suggestions!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it a bit frustrating to work with factors, to be honest. The mistake you made (and which I made several times before) is that this is simply not how you order levels of a factor, but for some reason, this is:

```
dm$cut <- factor(x = dm$cut, levels = c("Ideal",
                                        "Fair",
                                        "Very Good",
                                        "Premium",
                                        "Good"))
ggplot(dm, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I re-learned something new about R.

Comment: If this doesn't work, add an arguement `ordered = T` to the factor function.